# WebSockets, how to implement ping?

Tags: ruby, web, websocket, sinatra

I have created a WebSockets server in Sinatra/Faye Websocket. It has some built in capabilities of pinging the client, but it does not work. So I ping client manually using a thread which sleeps for N seconds and then sends something through sockets.

When I not implement ping, the connection is closed by client after 60 seconds of inactivity.

How to do it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would re-think if I would have to use the `ping` option... It's hardly utilized and I think Faye would have implemented a workflow if it was the best solution.

I would create a javascript timer that would send actual data over the websocket, calling an empty event.

If your server-side app ignores that data, you have an effective ping that is javascript based and would allow you some measure of control that might be missing from a simple `ping` (such as recording a user's last active time, like Facebook does, and other options).